# Flask MongoEngine dynamic ORM

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, flask, mongoengine

I'm implementing a simple CRUD application (react frontend + flask restful backend). During the implementation, I don't like hard code all schema, instead I'd like to have a table design functionality, which allows a user to design a collection (drag and drop fields and make up his own collection). Then the flask backend will accept this user designed schema and generate corresponding ORM for it. For example, the backend will accept such a schema

```js
[
  {
     title: 'full name',
     type: 'text',
     required: true,
  },
  {
     title: 'age',
     type: 'number',
     required: false,
  },
]
```

and it will define a ORM on the fly,

```py
class UserDefinedSchema:
    full_name = StringField(required=True)
    age = NumberField()
```

Finally, the React frontend can quires about schema, so it knows the form/table layout, and it can also do all corresponding CRUD operations.

---

Any ideas on how to implement this dynamic ORM?